# JavaScript, call private function as a string inside public method without using eval (Revealing pattern)

Tags: javascript, string, function, design-patterns, private

I'm trying to call a private function inside the revealing pattern. This is my code:

```
var module = (function(){
    var privateMethod = function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
    var publicMethod = function() {
        var functionString = "privateMethod";
        /** This what I tried
        functionString.call('test');
        window[module.privateMethod]('test');
        */
    }
    return {
        init: publicMethod
    }
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    module.init();
});
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your private functions properties of an object?

```
var module = (function(){
    var privateFuncs = {
        privateMethod: function(val) {
            console.log(val);
        }
    };
    var publicMethod = function() {
        var functionString = "privateMethod";
        privateFuncs[functionString]('test');
    };
    return {
        init: publicMethod
    };
})();
```

Your other attempts both fail, for different reasons:

- `functionString.call('test')` will never work because `functionString` refers to a string literal. It doesn't have a `call` method.
- `window[module.privateMethod]('test')` won't work because firstly, `module` doesn't have a property `privateMethod`. It wouldn't be "private" if it did. That means you're attempting to invoke `window[undefined]`, which is not a function.

Comment: This worked like a charm. The only "problem" is that I will need to reestructure all my private functions to mantain the same style.

Comment: @user1648170 - Why do you need to call all these functions by strings containing their identifiers? Can't you just do `privateMethod('test')` most of the time?

Comment: I'm attaching events on the fly using data-fields. Like this: '<a class="icons16-up-arrow" data-event="click" data-handler="up "data-index="' + index + '">Up</a>'; Using data-event to know what event fires the up handler :)

Comment: Very helpful answer...took me a little while to figure this out myself.