# Using deferred objects with private dynamic calling functions (Revealing pattern)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, private, deferred

I'm trying to use jQuery deferred with private dynamic calling functions like this:

```
var module = (function(){
    var privateFuncs = {
        privateMethod: function(val) {
            console.log(val);
        }
    };

    var success = function() {
        console.log('Success');
    };

    var publicMethod = function() {
        var functionString = "privateMethod";
        privateFuncs[functionString]('test').done(function(){
           success();
        });
    };

    return {
        init: publicMethod
    };
})();

module.init();
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
privateFuncs[functionString](...) is undefined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbelizon/pTaze/1/

Is there any chance to achieve what I'm looking for?

Without the use of deferred objects, the code works like a charm, as you can see here:

[JavaScript, call private function as a string inside public method without using eval (Revealing pattern)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294443/javascript-call-private-function-as-a-string-inside-public-method-without-using)

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's my new code:

```
var module = (function(){
    var privateFuncs = {
        privateMethod: function(val) {
            console.log(val);
        }
    };

    var success = function() {
        console.log('Success');
    };

    var publicMethod = function() {
        var functionString = "privateMethod";
        var deferred = $.Deferred(privateFuncs[functionString]('test'));
        deferred.done(function(){
           success();
        });
    };

    return {
        init: publicMethod
    };
})();

module.init();
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I create the deferred object, look at here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cbelizon/pTaze/3/

Comment: what is `done()` method here, i think is `undefined` is `done`, not `privateFuncs[functionString]`

Comment: With Chrome i'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined` which obviously makes sense since you don't return anything from `privateMethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct use of jQuery.Deferred:

```
var module = (function(){
    var privateFuncs = {
        privateMethod: function(val) {
            console.log(val);
        }
    };

    var success = function() {
        console.log('Success');
    };

    var publicMethod = function() {
        var functionString = "privateMethod";
        var deferred = $.Deferred(function(defer) {
            privateFuncs[functionString]('test');
            defer.resolve()
        });
        deferred.done(function(){
           success();
        });
    };

    return {
        init: publicMethod
    };
})();

module.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

A promise needs to be rejected or resolved. Try `deferred.resolve();` and your done-Callback should be invoked.

> When the Deferred is resolved, any doneCallbacks added by
>   deferred.then() or deferred.done() are called.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally get my objective done:

Here is the solution:

```
var module = (function(){
    var privateFuncs = {
        privateMethod: function(val) {
            alert(val);
        }
    };

    var success = function() {
        alert('Success');
    };

    var publicMethod = function() {
        var functionString = "privateMethod";
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        deferred.resolve(privateFuncs[functionString]('test'));
        deferred.done(function(){
           success();
        });
    };

    return {
        init: publicMethod
    };
})();

module.init();
```

I was misunderstanding the use of deferreds objects and the states of them.

Thanks!

Comment: `deferred.resolve(privateFuncs[functionString]('test'));` It's pointless to pass the function as an argument to resolve as it (`privateMethod` that is) returns nothing (undefined)

Comment: Why doesn't make sense not return nothing? I'm triying to fire the same action for every kind of handler that multiple events fires, like a callback for every kind of event.

Comment: Maybe in the general case then yes, but in this specific example you showed it's pointless.